# Save data from array in variable

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

**SOLVED!**

I`m trying save data from array in variable. I have in controller:

```
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
```

and I know that in this array are data about uploading file. One with this date is `"file_name"`, and I want to save this value in controller at variable. I try with:

```
$image_name= $data['file_name'];
```

But this not working. I use CodeIginter 2.1.3 framework.

**Good solution is: $data['upload_data']['file_name'];**
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = $this->upload->data();
```

then $data['file_name'] will work. The way you're doing it you're burying an array inside another array. Pretty sure you could call it with the following but it's still pointless

```
$data['upload_data']['file_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of CodeIgniter are you using?

With 2.1.3 it should work - Check out the last few paragraphs of the documentation at: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

The $data['file_name'] will give you the file name of the uploaded file if it has been successful.  To get the full name/path use the other fields in the array.

Comment: `A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: file_name

Filename: mod/upload.php

Line Number: 44`                                                 This line is: `$image=$data['file_name'];`

Comment: try: `$data['upload_data']['file_name'];`

Comment: you are assigning the values of the uploaded data into an array using `array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());`